# Add Sitecore 8 wffm reports to launchpad

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

We have recently implemented Sitecore 8.1 and installed the WFFM module which works great. However, I would like to add a button to the launchpad that takes users directly into the WFFM reporting but I don't know what the link would look like to display the "select a form" dialogue. Has anyone else done this or can you help direct me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

1) Go to Sitecore desktop and Switch to core database :

[image]

2) Navigate to : /sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons

3) You will find all launchpad sections here, Marketing, Content Editing, Tools, and Security

4) You can add it under any section or you can create your own section.

5) Let's say that you want to add it under Tools section, click right click add new "Launchpad-button"

6) There is a field called "Link" where you can link to WFFM Report page (**/sitecore/client/Applications/WFFM/Pages/FormReport.aspx?itemId=%7b0E8906B3-99BA-421E-A74D-277ED17A32FD%7d**), itemid should be your form id, and make "openiframe" checkbox field checked 
[image]

7) Now Switch back to Master Database and go to launchpad you will find it there :

[image]